# How To Display list view item pop up in xamarin form

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, popup

Hello Developer I want to display pop in my page. The given image link red portion I want to display please help me out how can I do that in xamarin form

[image]

```
Hello Xamarin developer I have attach one image link in this question .This image red mark portion I want display on my page how can I do that
```

Comment: Could do with Grid, and post your code of the page please.

Comment: how can I do that ,do you have any reference for that

Comment: @priyankapawar if you are using prism architecture then use prism dialog service to achieve your desired result. https://prismlibrary.com/docs/xamarin-forms/dialogs/dialog-service.html

Comment: checkout this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/picker may help

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is the content of your ListView, but here's the simple example of pop up with ListView in it, so you can adapt it as you like.

**XAML**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="TestPopUp.MainPage">
   <AbsoluteLayout Padding="0" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
      <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
         <Button Text="Pop up!" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="Center" Clicked="Button_Clicked" />
      </StackLayout>

      <ContentView x:Name="popupView" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Padding="10, 0" IsVisible="false" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0, 0, 1, 1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All">
         <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center">
            <Frame CornerRadius="10" Padding="0" BorderColor="LightGray">
               <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" HeightRequest="300" WidthRequest="200" BackgroundColor="White">
                  <ListView SeparatorVisibility="None" ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Never">
                     <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                           <ViewCell>
                              <Label Text="{Binding .}" />
                           </ViewCell>
                        </DataTemplate>
                     </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                  </ListView>
               </StackLayout>
            </Frame>
         </StackLayout>
      </ContentView>

   </AbsoluteLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

**C#**:

```
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public ObservableCollection<string> MyList { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            MyList.Add("Item 1");
            MyList.Add("Item 2");
            MyList.Add("Item 3");
            MyList.Add("Item 4");
            MyList.Add("Item 5");
            MyList.Add("Item 6");
            MyList.Add("Item 7");
            BindingContext = this;
        }

        private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            popupView.IsVisible = true;
        }
    }
```

This will give you output like this:

[image]

So, when you want to show this pop up, just put `popupView.IsVisible = true` in code behined.